# Type Error : Repository methods is not a function In NestJS & TypeORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am working with NestJs and TypeORM also using the generic repository pattern technique. But, I got an error when I call repository methods from the service class.

TypeError: this.todoRepository.findAll is not a function
at TodoService.findAllTodo (C:\STUDY\NestJS\Tutorial\nest-generic-repo-tut\src\todo\todo.service.ts:15:42)

I can't figure out what's going wrong.

## todo.module.ts file

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TodoController } from './todo.controller';
import { TodoService } from './todo.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Todo } from './todo.entity';
import { TodoRepository } from './todo.repository';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([TodoRepository])],
  controllers: [TodoController],
  providers: [TodoService,
    {
      provide: TodoRepository,
      useClass: Todo
    }
  ]
})
export class TodoModule { }
```

## todo.controller.ts file

```
import { Controller, Get, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TodoService } from './todo.service';
import { Todo } from './todo.entity';

@Controller('todo')
export class TodoController {

    constructor(private todoService: TodoService) { }

    @Post('')
    async createUser(todo: Todo) {
        return this.todoService.createUser(todo);
    }

    @Get('')
    async findAllTodo() {
        return this.todoService.findAllTodo();
    }
}
```

## todo.service.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TodoRepository } from './todo.repository';
import { Todo } from './todo.entity';

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {

    constructor(private todoRepository: TodoRepository<Todo>) { }

    async createUser(todo: Todo): Promise<Todo> {
        return await this.todoRepository.createTodo(todo);
    }

    async findAllTodo(): Promise<Todo[]> {
        return await this.todoRepository.findAll();
    }

    // async findAllTodo() {
    //     return this.todoRepository.call();
    // }
}
```

## todo.repository.ts file

```
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { IRepository } from './todo.interface';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';


export class TodoRepository<T> implements IRepository<T> {
    constructor(private repository: Repository<T>) { }

    async createTodo(item: T): Promise<T> {
        return await this.repository.save(item);
    }

    async findAll(): Promise<T[]> {
        return await this.repository.find();
    }

    // async findById(id: number): Promise<T> {
    //     return await this.repository.findOneBy({ id })
    // }

    async update(id: string, item: T): Promise<T> {
        const updatedItem = await this.repository.preload({
            id: id,
            ...item,
        });

        return await this.repository.save(updatedItem);
    }

    async delete(id: string): Promise<boolean> {
        const result = await this.repository.delete(id);
        return result.affected === 1;
    }

    call() {
        return "call methods";
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like you're treating `TodoRepository` as `Todo` entity, and they are clearly not the same. I didn't get why you have that provider `{ provide: TodoRepository, useValue: Todo }` since `Todo` isn't assignable to `TodoRepository`

Comment: Hi Micael Levi, Can you please tell me the solution... what should I do?

Comment: first of all, read the docs to understand what that `useValue` means. Then you'll be able to find a solution. I don't know exactly what you're trying to do here